# Trying to overwrite parquet file in an Azure Data Lake using PySpark in Databricks

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm overwriting the Delta table in data bricks and overwriting the Parquet file in Azure Data lake using pyspark.

```
(
                     df.write
                       .format("delta")
                       .mode("overwrite")
                       .partitionBy("year_id","month_id","time_key")
                       .option("replaceWhere", "time_key = {}".format("20231020"))
                       .save(/mnt/test/new/)
)
```

Here Delta table is  overwriting  but the Parquet file  is  creating multiple files in the Azure Data Lake when ever I ran.

Can any one suggest me what I'm missing here.

Comment: Can you share what you want to achieve, it is missing info of what you want to do

Comment: Databricks will split files into multiple files for better parallel read. Also, Delta tables will create new files on every run, to contain the new versions of the data

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to overwrite a Parquet file in ADLS, but instead of overwriting the file, multiple files are being created. This could be happening because of the way you are saving the file.

When you save a DataFrame as a Parquet file, PySpark creates multiple files by default. This is because Parquet is a columnar storage format, and each file contains a subset of the columns. However, if you want to overwrite an existing Parquet file with a single file, you can set the `coalesce` parameter to `1` before saving the file.

I have tried an example using the coalesce parameter to 1 before saving the file.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(parquet_path)
```

As you can see after using the `coalesce`  there is only 1 Partfile created in the ADLS.

[image]

**Also Overwriting the Delta table:**

```
df.write.format("delta").option("mergeSchema", "true").mode("overwrite").save(delta_path)
```

2nd Method:

When `autoCompact` is enabled, Spark will automatically execute the `OPTIMIZE` command to re-organize the data, resulting in more partitions if necessary

It is possible that the `autoCompact` option is not enabled for the Parquet file, which is why it is creating multiple files. You can try adding the `autoCompact` option to your code for the Parquet file as well and see if that resolves the issue.

The below is the code for `autocompact`
**Writing the data to Parquet with autoCompact option**

```
Parquet_file_path = f"abfss://<container Name>@<storageaccountname>.dfs.core.windows.net/parquet_folder"
df.write.mode("overwrite").option("autoCompact", "true").parquet(Parquet_file_path)
```

Comment: I will try the methods which you have  mentioned and update you

Comment: (
df.coalesce(1)
                       .write.format("parquet")
                       .write.format("delta")
                       .option("mergeSchema", "true")
                       .mode("overwrite")
                       .partitionBy("year_id","month_id","time_key")
                       .option("replaceWhere", "time_key = {}".format(timekey))
                       .save(path)
)

Comment: it is  giving  error like  this  'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: As you are using write method 2 time on same dataframe writer

Comment: df.coalesce(1) \
    .write \
    .format("delta") \
    .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .partitionBy("year_id", "month_id", "time_key") \
    .option("replaceWhere", "time_key = {}".format(timekey)) \
    .save(path)
try this once

Comment: it is overwriting delta table but  still is creating the paraquet file and it is not getting overwrite how delta table is getting overwritten.

Comment: df.coalesce(1) \ .write \ .format("parquet") \ .option("mergeSchema", "true") \ .mode("overwrite") \ .partitionBy("year_id", "month_id", "time_key") \ .option("replaceWhere", "time_key = {}".format(timekey)) \ .save(path)